# XSLT stripping comments

Tags: php, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I have a weird problem. Using XSLT transformations with PHP and for some reason, the compiled template file that is printed to the user strips all comments from the code. This never occurred before and have been unable to debug this problem at all. Even at the source $xslt->transformToXML($xml), it is stripped comments now, when it wasn't before.

This is particularly annoying with JS blocks that are wrapped in <!-- -->.

Any ideas?

Comment: "This never occurred before" - so what did change? Did you never use php/xsl? Or did you change the php version? Or did you change the template?

Comment: To say exactly why this is happening, we'll need to see the stylesheet. As answered by @Peter Tillemans, built-in rule for comments is to strip them. Maybe you strip an explicit rule for copying comments, maybe an identity rule...

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, unless you tell it otherwise, an XSLT transform will strip comments and processing instructions.

If you want to keep comments you can add something like

```
<xsl:template match="comment()">
  <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:comment>
</xsl:template>
```

to your xslt file.

Comment: your "AFAIK" is right. "The built-in template rule for processing instructions and comments is to do nothing." http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule +1 for supplying the needed template.

Comment: even simpler would be <xsl:template match="comment()"/><xsl:copy/></xsl:template>

Comment: @Nick when I do xhtml to xhtml transformation I usually add a copy everything template in the beginning and override what I want. But it is dangerous and surprising for unsuspected users.

Comment: @PeterTillemans What would be the difference between your solution and the one Nick Jones provided? I am not sure to see what could be dangerous and surprising in his solution. What does <xls:value-of select="."/> ? Why is this better than the other solution?  - Thanks for your time. :)

Comment: @ForceMagic The version of Nick is shorter and a more 'generic' solution. The value-of select="." will take the text in the current comment node and insert it in a comment. In this case both do the same thing.